# Repeater identification ending (CW)

Tags: cw, jargon

I am just starting to learn CW, and for practice I have been recording and transcribing repeater identifications that I hear. This is what I heard today:

DE W9KIC/R BBG

What is the meaning of "BBG"?

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!  Personally I've never heard of a repeater ID using "BBG".  Maybe you should ask W9KIC?  He lists an email address on qrz.com.

Comment: My guess would be it's either the initials of the club that owns the repeater or a some sort of abbreviation of the city it's in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The repeater is in Blacksburg according to an internet search, so BBG is almost definitely an abbreviation of that.